# Indexing in order to calculate with columns in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.4.4 with Pandas 0.18.1 to determine confidence intervals for experimental data. This leads to many calculations with datframe columns.
From [Pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) the .loc[] method is recommended over the chained[] method, but it seems to be impossible to apply. Here an example with a simplified dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), index=['a','b','c'], columns=['A','B','C'])
print(df1)
   A  B  C
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9
```

To calculate column 'A' times 3 in a new column 'E' I try

```
df1.loc[:,'E'] = df1.loc[:,['A']]*3
print(df1)
   A  B  C   E
a  1  2  3 NaN
b  4  5  6 NaN
c  7  8  9 NaN
```

If I use the un-recommended method I obtain

```
df1.loc[:,'E'] = df1['A']*3
print(df1)
   A  B  C   E
a  1  2  3   3
b  4  5  6  12
c  7  8  9  21
```

Thus it looks like the second method is the good one, but for my larger dataframe I get

> "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

I spend a lot of time to find a satifying solution, without result.
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `df1['E'] = df1['A']*3` is more standard way for creating new columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), index=['a','b','c'], columns=['A','B','C'])
print(df1)
df1['E']= df1['A']*3
print(df1)

output:
   A  B  C
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9
   A  B  C   E
a  1  2  3   3
b  4  5  6  12
c  7  8  9  21
```